# multilanguage lang file replace some pattern to dynamic content

Tags: php, multilingual

currently i'm working on a project which need to support multi language,i have write a simple function to do this, here to ask is there better way to return language var using include langfile?

this is where i write the translate file.

```
class OhHelper
{
    //.... Other function

    public static function t($filename, $msg = '', $arr = array())
    {
        $lang = defined('lang_select') ? lang_select : lang;

        $file = ROOT . DS . 'language' . DS . $lang . DS . $filename . '.php';

        if(file_exists($file))
        {
            $lang = include $file;

            if($msg == '')
            {
                //return the whole language array
                return $lang;
            }

            if(array_key_exists($msg, $lang))
            {
                if(preg_match('/\{[\d+]\}/', $lang[$msg], $matched))
                {
                    if(count($matched) > 0)
                    {
                        $langReplace = $lang[$msg];
                        foreach($matched as $key => $var)
                        {
                            $langReplace = preg_replace('/\{[\d+]\}/', $arr[$key], $langReplace);
                        }

                        return $langReplace;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //return the selected lang(there is no {\d} to replace
                    return $lang[$msg];
                }
            }
        }

        return 'lang file not found';
    }

}
```

and here is the language file

```
return array(
    'welcome good to see you again' => 'Welcome {1}, good to see you again',
    'good bye see you again' => 'Bye {1}, see you',
);
```

here is how i call and successfully replace the content

```
echo OhHelper::t('general', 'welcome good to see you again', array('username'));
```

currently this function is workable, but i'm looking for better performance,
i guess repeat every text with this **OhHelper::t()** is really slow when there is a lot of content(i guess)

and i'm doing in MVC pattern so i think another way

every controller construct **$this->lang = OhHelper('controller', '')**

but this way i can't replace the {1} pattern with dynamic content and only can do something like

```
echo $this->lang['welcome']; echo '&nbsp;'; echo 'username'; echo $this->lang['see you again'];
```

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't matter how you manage your languages for performance, because you should focus on how to cache it. ;)

Comment: but cache cannot output dynamic content like date, username?

Comment: Em, dynamic content has nothing to do with languages. I mean that you don't have to read entire file and looking for message every time when you are asking for same translation entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use tags like you, but not numeric and it doesn't require regexes. Running a regex for every call it might slow your application.

Instead of `{1}` you could use `{username}` and when you call:

```
echo OhHelper::t('general', 'welcome good to see you again', array('username'));
```

you should use the key of that array with name of the replace:

```
echo OhHelper::t('general', array('username' => 'welcome good to see you again'));
```

and in the `OhHelper class`, you just iterate the array parameter and `str_replace` all.

**Later Edit:**

As a note, never use regexes unless there is no other way. Try to avoid them, because if you don't optimize them, they can be really slow.